# JNLP Launched App started caching all URLs

Tags: java, jnlp

We have a Java client/server app that downloads via jnlp launch (local machine has latest Java 7). When we compiled it for Java 7 it suddenly started caching urls that are not jars. In the Java 6 compile it will cache jars, but does not cache the other URLs. This is important because the jnlp cache causes the app to immediately be out of date.

How can I cause Java to cache the jars but not cache other resources?
Thanks, I think that I read a thread that discussed this, but I can't find that thread any longer.

Comment: I found another thread that provides an answer that helped me. Look at the last answer in this thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908826/java-webstart-and-urlconnection-caching-api

Basically, Java7 turns on url caching as the default. This speeds up simple applets, but it is terrible for dynamic applications because the moment a user changes the data (via a request to the server) then the cached version of the url (query) is out of date.

Setting URLConnection.setUseCaches(false) fixed my application.